# Problema al manejar roles con Middleware para gestionar acceso a diferentes tipos de usuario

Tags: laravel

Estoy desarrolando un sistema en Laravel y tengo dos tipos de usuario Administrador y Usuario
aqui esta el codigo en el Kernel:

Kernel.php

```
 //Agregado para Login de Usuarios
    'Administrador'=>\App\Http\Middleware\Administrador::class,
    'Usuario'=>\App\Http\Middleware\Usuario::class,
```

Aca esta el codigo en la ruta donde filtro que usuario ve que cosa

Web.php

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });   

    Auth::routes();
});



Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
   
    

    
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Administrador']], function () {
        
        Route::resource('MisDatos', 'MisDatosController');
    
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Usuario']], function () {

        //Route::resource('MisDatos', 'MisDatosController');

    });


});
```

La ruta para Guest y Auth funciona sin problemas,  las rutas para El administrador el la puede ver, pero tambien la puede ver el usuario y necesito que solo la vea el administrador y el usuario no tenga acceso a ella.

¿otra duda que tengo es se puede bloquear el controlador en Laravel?, en caso de que se pueda ¿Que es mas optimo bloquear rutas o controlador o ambas?

Comment: Te recomiendo https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction

Answer (score 0):

para empezar tienes que sacar   `Auth::routes();` del grupo de `Guest`.

bloquear el controlador o rutas no creo que sea lo mejor.

si quieres tener control sobre los métodos `index`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`.

puedes hacer algo así dentro de los controladores.

```php
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->only(['store', 'destroy']);
        $this->middleware('guest')->only('show');
    }
```